# Add CSS rules from textarea using v-html

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, wysiwyg

I am building a WYSIWYG type application where a user can write CSS in a textarea and that CSS rule will be applied to the HTML on page i tried something like this in template

```
<textarea v-bind="css"></textarea>
<style v-html="css"></style>
```

VueCompilerError: Tags with side effect ( and ) are ignored in client component templates.

Comment: instead of `<style v-html="css"></style>` do `<div :style="css"></div>`, also `v-bind="css"` should be `v-model="css"` cover the basics first

Comment: I tried this `<textarea v-model="css"></textarea> <div :style="css"></div>` didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Old answer, below is better one

> Add textarea with v-model:
>
> ```
> <textarea v-model="css" />
> ```
>
> You can create style tag in onMounted hook:
>
> ```
> onMounted(() => {
>   const style = document.createElement("style");
>   style.type = "text/css";
>   updateCss(style, css.value);
>
>   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
>
>   el.value = style;
> });
> ```
>
> You must be able to access this element later, so assign style to
> el.value.
>
> Then add watch on input value:
>
> ```
> watch(css, () => {
>   updateCss(el.value, css.value);
> });
> ```
>
> Where updateCss is a function:
>
> ```
> const updateCss = (el, css) => {
>   if (el.styleSheet) {
>     el.styleSheet.cssText = css.value;
>   } else {
>     el.innerHTML = "";
>     el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> Demo:
>
> https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-mestorf-uqz6f?file=/src/App.vue:246-463

### Edit

I found much better solution:

```
<template>
  <textarea v-model="css" />
  <component :is="'style'" type="text/css" v-text="css"></component>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const css = ref("body { background-color: blue; }");
    return { css };
  },
};
</script>
```

Component doesn't throw the error about style tag:

```
<component :is="'style'">
```

**Note that there is v-text instead v-html. V-html could be unsafe.**

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-germain-q9tg3?file=/src/App.vue:122-281

Comment: I thought of this but was not sure if this is the proper way, anyway thanks a lot

Comment: @Kalpesh I found another much cleaner solution. I edited my post.

Comment: @ Cianekjr That is so much cleaner can you explain or link me to better understand <component :is="'style'">

Comment: @Kalpesh
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components
It is usually used to switch between components. You can have variable like componentName and then if you do <component :is="componentName"/>, you can change your variable and dynamically render html tags or vue components.

/// <component :is="'li'"/>x</component> => <li>x</li>///

///<component :is="MyComponent"/>x</component> => <MyComponent>x</MyComponent>///

So <component :is="'style'"><component> is rendered as <style></style>, but it doesn't throw an error the <style></style> does.